# GCC: Specify target address for actual symbol

Tags: c, gcc, linker, symbols

knowing that similar questions have been asked a few times already, let me just explain what I'm trying to do and why: I have an embedded system which consists of an ARM Cortex-M4 microcontroller and an FPGA. The FPGA can be configured by an on-board flash memory without even needing the microcontroller. But sometimes it would be nice for the microcontroller to be able to reconfigure the FPGA, so it has access to the required programming signals.

The bitstream which needs to be sent to the FPGA is some 150kBytes, but changes much less frequently than the MCU firmware. Since programming that much data with the programmer/debugger (Segger J-Link) takes some time, I would prefer not to erase and reprogram this bitstream every time the firmware changes (but the bitstream is identical). The debugger does reprogram only those memory blocks which actually have changed, so it happily skipped programming of the bitstream if it would always be located at the same address. But this is obviously not the case if I just include it some way like

```
static const uint8_t fpga_bitstream[] = {
  // ...
};
```

since the linker is free to decide where to place this data.

Now the question: What would be a (not too intrusive) way to have the linker put this symbol always to the same address? I am aware of the `--defsym` linker option, but this seems to be ignored when the symbol in question is defined in a source file (instead of just being referenced and declared as `extern`). The only way I know which works (I've used that some time ago already) is to use a custom linker file which defines a separate partition in the `MEMORY` part and then creates a new section to put the symbol into, using e.g.

```
static const uint8_t fpga_bitstream[] __attribute__((section(".fpgabitstream"))) = {
  // ...
};
```

This project uses a small operating system ([Nut/OS](http://ethernut.de/)), however, which brings its own linker files. So I'd be fine if I could append some data to it using the `-Tfile.ld` option, but I'd prefer not having to change the original script, as this is located in the source tree of the operating system itself.

Thanks,
Philipp

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do this without modifications to your linker script (but would be very interested if somebody found one). If you specify a linker script on the command line with `-T`, it will replace the "default" script. You can however specify additional linker script commands in separate text files and just add them to the command line as if they were object files (these will extend what's already there in the "default" script), but `ld` doesn't accept additional sections in such files

Comment: The method you described is really the correct and normal way to do this. You seem to know what you're doing, is it really that hard to just add a new section to the linker script? Presumably this is just a hack for during development to speed your load times, so you can swap back the normal linker script when you're done.

Comment: @mfro: I don't use the "default" linker script anyway, it's always the one supplied by the OS. According to [the LD command language](http://www.math.utah.edu/docs/info/ld_3.html), there may indeed be at most one `MEMORY` and one `SECTIONS` - well - _section_ in a linker script. It's a pity.
@Jon: It's not _that hard_ to modify the linker script, I'm rather just curios if it's possible to do in a simpler way. I mean, the task itself seems trivial, just tell the linker where to put some symbol in its symbol table...

Answer (score 0):

As it doesn't seem to be possible to "add" to an existing linker script, probably the easiest solution would be to reserve a separate area of flash (e.g. an area at a fixed address near end with a little reserve for future growth) for the FPGA configuration and load from that fixed address.

Since there is probably nothing useful you can do to the FPGA bitstream anyway from the MCU side (other than loading it), I don't see any advantage in embedding the FPGA config into your MCU binary. You only need start address and size in your MCU code, both of which can be made known to the MCU by the `--defsym` linker option (without linker script modification).

I have a very similar configuration (with FPGA config and MCU code living on separate areas of flash) over here which works well. MCU flash is used regularily while FPGA is flashed only now and then.

Comment: Well, then how to _reserve a seperate area of flash_ without modifying the linker script? Of course, I could simply say that the flash is big enough (512kiB), so there will always be some 155kiB free at its end, but this seems to be a bit fragile. And if I don't put the bitstream into the binary, then how to program it into the MCU? The debugger could handle this with some separate commands, but this would probably cause more problems than it solves. Thanks for the suggestions anyway!